# Why can I not call my function inside the render ()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new using React and I have the following problem; I have defined a function out of the `return ()`, and I am calling it afterwards so it shows only when the page is loaded.

```js
class Landing extends Component {
  render() {
    scrollbar = () => {
      const progress = document.getElementById("progressBar");
      const totalHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
      window.onscroll = function () {
        const progressHeight = (window.pageYOffset / totalHeight) * 100;
        progress.style.height = progressHeight + "%";
      };
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div id="progressBar"> {this.scrollbar()}</div>
        <div id="scrollPath"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The error that I get is:

> "scrollbar is undefined" // Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Since `scrollbar` is not part of the class, move it app to be a class function and only then you'll be able to use the `this` keyword to access it

Answer (score 2):

You must define the method (scrollbar) above the render method.

```
class Landing extends Component {
    scrollbar = () => {
      const progress = document.getElementById("progressBar");
      const totalHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
      window.onscroll = function () {
        const progressHeight = (window.pageYOffset / totalHeight) * 100;
        progress.style.height = progressHeight + "%";
      };
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div id="progressBar">{this.scrollbar}</div>
        <div id="scrollPath"></div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope this solve your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be doing DOM manipulation like that when using react, so ideally you would rewrite the `scrollbar` function to be more inline with react.

The error you are getting is because `this` is referring to the class, meaning `this.scrollbar` is looking for a class property called scrollbar. You do not have a class property called scrollbar, but a function declared within the `render` method.

You have two options to solve this error.

Reference the function instead of a class property:

```js
<div id="progressBar">{scrollbar()}</div>
```

Change the function to be a class property:

```js
class Landing extends Component {
  scrollbar = () => {
    const progress = document.getElementById("progressBar");
    const totalHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    window.onscroll = function () {
      const progressHeight = (window.pageYOffset / totalHeight) * 100;
      progress.style.height = progressHeight + "%";
    };
  };
```

Once you do one of these, you still might see some unexpected behavior. By doing:

```js
<div>{this.scrollbar()}</div>
```

You are rendering the result of the function call. The function has no return value though, so it will render `undefined`. Since it really doesn't need to be rendered, you can just call in inside the render function directly:

```js
render() {
  this.scrollbar();

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="progressBar"></div>
      <div id="scrollPath"></div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1) Move your scrollbar function outside render.

2) remove () these braces while calling scrollbar inside render function.

```
  scrollbar = () => {
   const progress = document.getElementById("progressBar");
   const totalHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
   window.onscroll = function () {
     const progressHeight = (window.pageYOffset / totalHeight) * 100;
     progress.style.height = progressHeight + "%";
   };
};

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div id="progressBar"> {this.scrollbar}</div>
    <div id="scrollPath"></div>
```

Comment: Incorrect, `this` refers to the class, while the funciton is not

Comment: i have tried many times but when we have arrow function then it does not work with () these braces.

Comment: I'm not going into specifics but now it looks syntacticly correct, I removed the downvote

Comment: You can. As written this function will never fire. You pass references to event handlers like `onClick` instead of calling them with `()`, because the user is going to trigger the function call, you don't want it called every render. In this case however, you do want it called every render. So you should be using `this.scrollbar()`